# Encontrando resultado de pesquisa em campos personalizados

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Como faz para o Wordpress fazer busca em campos personalizado?

Eu pesquisei e vi que a busca dele funciona usando o o título e o conteúdo do content. Eu criei um projeto que usa campos personalizado, como:
endereço e número de telefone, com a possibilidade do usuário digitar o **nome da cidade**, **endereço**, **estado** ou **telefone**.

O nome da cidade esta o título normal, o restante dos campos são todos personalizados.

Eu estou usando uma query pra fazer isso, pois estou exibindo o resultado via ajax

```
$string = $_GET['string'];
$argumentos = [
    'post_type' => 'unidade',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's' => $string
];
$posts = new WP_Query($argumentos);
?>
```

Comment: Qual a questão ao certo? O que pretende fazer?

Comment: Que o wordpress efetue a busca nos campos personalizados também

Comment: Coloque a sua query na pergunta

Comment: @lazyFox coloquei é bem simples

Comment: Não estou familiarizado com `Wordpress` mas enquanto aguarda uma resposta veja este [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-custom-fields--cms-23091)